# Book Recommendation for Studying Stochastic Optimization Problem with Almost Sure Constraint

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, book-recommendation

I was begin to study the following type of stochastic optimization problem:

> Let $u(k)$ and $X(k)$ are discrete random variables for all $k =1,2,...,N$ and $f$ be any concave function and $g$ be continuous function. Consider the constrained optimization problem as
>   $$
> \max_{u(k)} E[f(u(k),X(k))]
> $$
>   subject to $|u(k)| \le g(X(k))$ almost surely.

My first idea is to reformulate above as optimal control problem and try to solve it by using Pontryagin Maximum Principle  (PMP) but I stuck at very beginning since PMP only works for deterministic case (and also not sure how to check the derivative conditions..) ...

I was wondering is there any recommended books/papers (which is suitable for newcomer) for studying such problem? or for its special case. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is meant by $\max_{u(k)} E[f(u(k), X(k))]$?  In particular, is $k$ supposed to be random, or is this for some particular fixed $k \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$?  Do you really mean to maximize $E[\max[f(u(1), X(1)), ..., f(u(N), X(N))]]$? Or maximize $\sum_{k=1}^N E[f(u(k), X(k))]$?

Comment: Also, is $u(k)$ supposed to be a decision variable on step $k$, so it is chosen in some set, say, set $\mathcal{U}$?  Perhaps $u(k)$ is chosen based on knowledge of $X(k)$?   How does $X(k)$ depend on $u(1), \ldots, u(k-1)$? The problem needs more description to be understood.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Michael, $k$ is nonrandom index. and I want to find a sequence of $\{u(1),u(2),...,u(N)\}$ so that maximize $E[f(u(k),X(k)]$ subject to $|u(k)| \le g(X(k))$ almost surely. and in my situation, $u$ is also dependent on $X$...

Comment: Maximization problems only make sense when maximizing scalar quantities.  Typically, you cannot simultaneously maximize all components of a vector.  So, simultaneously maximizing all components of $(E[f(u(1),X(1)), \ldots, E[f(u(N),X(N))])$ does not make sense.  Perhaps you want to find a Pareto optimal point, such as maximzing a weighted sum? That is why I suggested maximizing $\sum_{k=1}^N E[f(u(k),X(k))]$ as something reasonable to maximize.

Comment: The way in which the past influences the future is important, as are state space issues, so those would need to be specified.  I suspect that $X(k)$ is a system state (perhaps finite?) and that $(X(k), u(k))$ influences the transition probability matrix on step $k$.  You should google books on "dynamic programming" and/or "Markov decision problems."

Comment: In my third comment (which I deleted to clarify), I meant this:  If $X(k)$ has no dependence on $\{u(1), \ldots, u(k-1)\}$, and you really just want to separately maximize $E[f(u(k),X(k))]$ for each $k$, just do this:  Observe $X(k)$ and choose $u(k) \in \mathcal{U}$ as the maximizer of $f(u(k),X(k))$ over all $u(k) \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $|u(k)|\leq g(X(k))$.  Then, almost surely, $f(u(k),X(k))\leq f(U,X(k))$ for all random variables $U \in \mathcal{U}$ that (almost surely) satisfy $|u(k)|\leq g(X(k))$.  So take expectations of both sides.